# javascript how to encode url,which has '-'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass parameter to a URL like this:

```
bike-my-myRecharge-dailyAccount-detail.html?billTime=2016-02
```

but the URL I get is always:

```
bike-my-myRecharge-dailyAccount-detail.html?billTime=2013
```

I've tried `encodeURIComponent()` and `encodeURI()`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post the code you use to add the parameter to the URL.

Comment: `2016`....`2013` ? How ?

Comment: Is completely valid to have `-` in url. Do you have ani issue with: http://7-zip.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried encodeURIComponent() and encodeURI(), but it doesn't work.

Can you please post the error that you are seeing.

```
//test url
var uri = "my test.com?bike-my-myRecharge-dailyAccount-detail.html?billTime=2016-02";

var res = encodeURI(uri);
```

`-` will be encoded to `%2D`

You can directly test your encoded url in [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)